# Integrating SqlCipher with android application (on Windows)

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse, sqlcipher

I don't really understand from the following documentation: http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

What I should do, what are the steps? It seems like the instructions belong only to MAC users, My OS is Windows 7.

Could anyone tell me what should I do please? the binaries contains "libs" and "assets" folders.
How can I integrate these to my existing app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step #1: Copy the contents of the `assets/` folder into your project's `assets/` folder.

Step #2: Copy the contents of the `libs/` folder into your project's `libs/` folder.

Step #3: Code to the SQLCipher API, replacing references to things like `SQLiteDatabase` and `SQLiteOpenHelper` with their SQLCipher equivalents.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure) showing SQLCipher for Android in use.

Comment: By copy, you mean just like CTRL+C ?

Comment: @idish: I mean copy the files. You are welcome to use whatever means you wish to copy the files.

Comment: ok I copied the files and added the 3 jars as libraries and it works well! thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I might be Off Topic now a little, but the usement of the sqlcipher is just the same? I mean the encrypting and decrypting is happening automatically?

Comment: @idish: Yes, it is automatic. You provide the passphrase when you open the database (e.g., passed to `getReadableDatabase()` on your `SQLiteOpenHelper`).

Comment: in http://sqlcipher.net/design/ link they provide only command for terminal ..any command for dos also